# Robot class in unix through selenium

Tags: unix, selenium-chromedriver

I have selenium code running on windows which contains the Robot class and does some functions with keyboard interaction like ctrl V, Ctrl C, etc.
Can I run this same script through Unix (through Jenkins job)? Does Unix support this keyboard mouse event?

I tried this is windows and it is running fine but I want to run this code through Unix.

My script failed when I run as it is, do we need to change anything.

Comment: What was the script? How was it failing?

Comment: Robot robot = new Robot(); robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

Comment: so will this code work when we run through Unix , I am planning to run my script through Jenkins while my code will be on Unix server .

Comment: anybody could you please suggest here

Comment: Have you tried running it on Unix? What happened?

Comment: script fails when I run this code of Robot class , can we use Robot class in unix ?

Comment: How does the script fail? What is exactly happening?

Comment: I am running through jenkins on unix server and when this line of code executes script fails and stop executing further . So my question was has anybody tried this before ? OR can we run such script in Unix which is having keyboard interaction

Comment: any suggestion please